# PHP and javascript (EXTJS) - validate form fields in server side OOP way

Tags: javascript, php, validation, oop, extjs

In my app the form fields are validated on the client side with javascript (EXTJS).

Although I'not experienced in PHP OOP,  I also want to validate them server side with PHP OOP way.

For this - after studying the various possibilities of validation - I am using the following code:

I'm following this example: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MlJJyva75t8#t=38.9063742

**class Validator**

```
<?php

class Validator {

private $fields = array();
private $field_errors = array();
private $form_is_valid = true;

private $allErrors = array(); //added » edited


public function addField($field_name){
    $this->fields[] = $field_name;
    $this->field_errors[$field_name] = array();
}

public function addValidationRule($field_name, $field_rule, $value){
    $rule_name = $field_rule[0];

    switch($rule_name){

        case 'empty':
            if(strlen($value) == 0){
                $this->addValidationError($field_name, ucwords($field_name). " error msg empty");
            }
        break;

        case 'min_lenght':
            if(strlen($value) < $field_rule[1]){
                $this->addValidationError($field_name, ucwords($field_name). " error msg min_lenght");
            }
        break;

    }
}

private function addValidationError($field_name, $error_message){
    $this->form_is_valid = false;
    $this->field_errors[$field_name][] = $error_message;
}

public function formValid(){
    return $this->form_is_valid;
}

public function outValidationError($field_name){
     if(isset($this->field_errors[$field_name])){
         foreach($this->field_errors[$field_name] as $field_error){
             //$allErrors[] = $field_error;
             $this->allErrors[] = $field_error;//added » edited
         }
     }
 }

public function outAllValidationError(){
     foreach($this->fields as $field){
         $this->outValidationError($field);
     }
     return $this->allErrors; //added » edited » works ok
 }

}

?>
```

**Query with prepared statements**

```
<?php

require('conect.php');
$action = $_REQUEST['action'];

switch($action){

  case "create":{

    $records = $_POST['records'];
    $data = json_decode(stripslashes($records));

    $cars = $data->{'cars'};


    if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {

        require_once('validator.php');
        $validator = new Validator();

        $validator->addField('cars');
        $validator->addValidationRule('cars', array('min_lenght', 4), $cars);
        $validator->addValidationRule('cars', array('empty'), $cars);

        if($validator->formValid()){

                $sqlQuery = "INSERT INTO the_cars (cars)
                            VALUES (?)";

                if($statement = $con->prepare($sqlQuery)){
                    $statement->bind_param("s", $cars);
                    $statement->execute();
                    $success= true;
                }else{
                    $erro = $con->error;
                    $success = false;
                }
        }else{
            $allErrors = $validator->outAllValidationError(); 
            $success = false;

        }

        echo json_encode(array(
            "success" => $sucess,
            'errors'=> $erro,
            'errorsValidation'=> $allErrors 
        ));

        $statement->close();
        $conexao->close();

        break;
    }
?>
```

y problem is to export the array of validation errors to the client side with json encode.

If in the **outValidacionError()** function I uncomment **print_r ($ allErrors)** and make a form submit with the cars field empty it prints the error on console.

However, I am not able to send these errors to the client side. What is missing?

I appreciate suggestions for improving the code or other solution.

**EDITED:**

As my json_decode is done for objects and not for an associative array, I have changed the code to make it compatible with the decode that was made, adding $value to addValidationRule()

**EDITED**

code edited with correct solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use functions to encapsulate behaviour, you should not try to use global variables to store their output. Their side-effects should be minimal and they should only manipulate their own object's properties, if required.

Your `$allErrors` variable is declared nowhere, especially not as a global variable. So when you fill it inside the function, you get a locally scoped variable that will be thrown away once the function finishes.

You may want to return them from your function

```
return $allErrors;
```

and then get the values from the function call:

```
$allErrors = $validator->outAllValidationError()
```

Comment: I edited the code with some modifications and according to Alexander's suggestions. With print_r () in class Validator I get the error messages but I am not able to send the data in json when I call the outAllValidationErrors () function. $allErrors is null.

Comment: You return the value inside an if clause; have you checked that the if clause evaluates to `true`? What should happen if the clause evaluates to false?

Comment: Thanks again Alexander. Works well if  return $this->allErrors is in outAllValidationErrors() function after foreach loop.